# Scala Future blocks transformations?

Tags: scala, future, executioncontext

I have the following test code snippet:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.util.Success

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object FutureAndThen extends App {

  val future = Future {
    println("Started initial Future")
    10
  } andThen { case Success(value) =>
    println("Started callback")
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println(s"Finished callback: value = $value")
  } map { x =>
    println("Chained transformation")
    x * 2
  }

  println(Await.result(future, Duration.Inf))

}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Started initial Future
Started callback
Finished callback: value = 10
Chained transformation
20
```

I expect `andThen` callback to be executed asynchronously. But the actual execution is the next:

1. Execute original future
2. Execute **asynchronous** callback
3. Run transformations (`map`)

At first I thought that the issue is in `ExecutionContext` which decided to run all these operations in single thread. And I changed this to use custom `ExecutionContext`:

```
implicit val ctx = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
  (command: Runnable) => new Thread(command).start()
)
```

And the result is the same. Could you advice me what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is actually documented for [`Future.andThen`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html#andThen[U](pf:PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[T],U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]):

> Applies the side-effecting function to the result of this future, and returns
>    a ***new future*** with the result of this future.
>   
>  
>   
>   This method allows one to ***enforce*** that the callbacks are executed in a ***specified order***.

It means that `map` will not start its job before the calculations inside `andThen` are completed. If this is not what you want, you have to call `map` on the original `Future`. And then you can use `onComplete` instead of `andThen`, so code would become something like this:

```
  val future = Future {
    println("Started initial Future")
    10
  }

  future onComplete { case Success(value) =>
    println("Started callback")
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println(s"Finished callback: value = $value")
  }

  val f2 = future map { x =>
    println("Chained transformation")
    x * 2
  }

  println(Await.result(f2, Duration.Inf))
```

P.S. AFAIK there is no standard `onComplete` equivalent that can be used with method chaining and I think this is by design to make it easier to predict behavior by reading the code. Currently you can use a simple rule: if it is chained - it is executed later.